# Hokuyo laser getID failed. How to fix it?

Tags: hokuyo-node, hokuyo, youbot, hokuyo-laser, timeout

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While running the rosrun hokuyo_node, I get the error
getID failed: timeout reached (in hokuyo::laser::laserReadLine)

how to fix it.
I followed the Hokuyo tutorials.
And I have given it permission.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213196/hokuyo-laser-getid-failed.-how-to-fix-it?/) by [Truce](https://answers.ros.org/users/22690/truce/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2015-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure the laser driver is installed correctly and the system can read it.
Connect your laser and check if the system can detect it and if it is configured correctly.

```
$ ls -l /dev/ttyACM0
```

When the laser is connected, the system can see it using the following command line:

```
crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialout 166, 0 Jun 15 11:17 /dev/ttyACM0
```

Once everything is OK, we are going to switch on the laser. Start  roscore in one
shell and in another shell execute the following command:

```
$ rosrun hokuyo_node hokuyo_node
```

If everything is fine, you will see the following output:

```
[ INFO] [1378076340.184643618]: Connected to device with ID: H10XX40X
```

---

Originally posted by [redskydeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/22936/redskydeng/) with karma: 118 on 2015-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Truce](https://answers.ros.org/users/22690/truce/) on 2015-07-10**:
Yes I did whatever you said.
It worked fine till :
crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialout 166, 0 Jun 15 11:17 /dev/ttyACM0

then trying to get ID i was getting error.
Somehow after taking a break and restarting everything. It worked.
Thanks for your help.

**Comment by [85pando](https://answers.ros.org/users/23227/85pando/) on 2015-09-25**:
On the youbot there should also be a `/dev/sensors/hokuyo` symlink that you can set by:

```
$ rosparam set hokuyo_node/port /dev/sensors/hokuyo
```